# How to set upload_max_filesize in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have try to put these 2 lines

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

In my root `.htaccess` file but that brings me "internal server error" message.

php5 is running on the server

I don't have access to php.ini so I think `htaccess` is my only chance.
Can you tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`php_value upload_max_filesize 30M` is correct.

You will have to contact your hosters -- some don't allow you to change values in php.ini

Comment: Thank you but ini_set() is not working for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size :/

Comment: when you say "not working" do you mean, not bringing about the desired result / producing an error / something else?

Comment: set error_reporting( E_ALL ) and see if anything shows. Other than that, contact your host provider, they should be able to help you. Some block changes to such variables as they don't want you to become a major trafficked site.

Comment: These options can not be set by ini_set(). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php and http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: Many hosts dont allow this but you can also create a php.ini file, put it in the root of the site and override the values there.

Answer (score 44):

```
php_value memory_limit 30M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

Use all 3 in `.htaccess` after everything at last line. `php_value post_max_size` must be more than than the remaining two.

Comment: may I know the reason why `php_value post_max_size` must be more than the remaining two?

Comment: @Anusha if you think about it, you could be doing a post with two 30M files + more textual data, and that will cost some additional bytes, that's probably the reason

Answer (score 41):

If you are getting **500 - Internal server error** that means you don't have permission to set these values by **.htaccess**. You have to contact your web server providers and ask to set `AllowOverride Options` for your host or to put these lines in their virtual host configuration file.

Comment: Thank you. The error log gave some nonsense about invalid command, which is a far throw from "Go change your virtual host configuration file."

Comment: If you are getting a 500 internal server error an alternative solution would be to use a '.user.ini' file to change the settings. By adding 'post_max_size = 30M' and 'upload_max_filesize = 30M'

Answer (score 13):

What to do to correct this is create a file called php.ini and save it in the same location as your .htaccess file and enter the following code instead:

```
upload_max_filesize = "250M"
post_max_size = "250M"
```

Comment: This will only work on some hosting environments. Worked for me on my Web Fusion hosting account.

Answer (score 3):

If your web server is running php5, I believe you must use `php5_value`.  This resolved the same error I received when using `php_value`.

Answer (score 3):

I also face `internal server error` message for inserting
`php_value upload_max_filesize 5M` in my `.htaccess` file in PHP Laravel Project from c-Panel.

Then I solve it by the following logic -

1. Create a file named - `.user.ini` in my Project root Directory
2. Insert the following code in `.user.ini` file

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M  
post_max_size = 5M
```

Answer (score -2):

Both commands are correct

```
php_value post_max_size 30M
```

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

BUT to use the `.htaccess` you have to enable `rewrite_module` in Apache config file. In `httpd.conf` find this line:

```
# LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and remove the `#`.

Comment: IMHO, to enable the use of .htaccess, all you need to do is set `AllowOverride` to anything but `none`. Loading the `rewrite_module` is only required for ModRewrite-directives.