# why my action attribute is not working in the below code

Tags: php, html, forms

```
    //Here i have mentioned one form and gave action in that.I also gave a button submit.Now when I click on the submit button, It the action given in the form is not perfoming.



<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
            <tbody>
                <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" class="hidden">
                <td data-name="loannum">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" required>
                </td>
                <td data-name="name">
                  <input id="startdate" name="startdate" min="2016-01-01" max="2020-01-01" type="date" class="form-control">
                </td>
                <td data-name="name">
                    <input type="text" name='gname' placeholder='Group Name' class="form-control"  pattern="([A-z\s]){2,}" required/>
                </td>
                <td data-name="desc">
                    <input type="number" placeholder='Batch Number' class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{9}" required>
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#84ca71;color:#F44336;padding-bottom:24px;">Add Group</a>
//here we mentioned a button and when we click on it the action given in form should be performed
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"  style="background:#cddc39;color:#F44336;padding:5px 30px 25px 20px;">submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: where is your button ?

Comment: u forgot to add button and `</form>`

Comment: offo I forgot to link that code. so here is the button code.</div>
 </div>
 <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#84ca71;color:#F44336;padding-bottom:24px;">Add Group</a>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"  style="background:#cddc39;color:#F44336;padding:5px 30px 25px 20px;">submit</button>
</form>

Comment: ok it means, u are using </form> also, add this in your quesion. and add `print_r($_POST)` in `submit.php`

Comment: If after you make changes which are in answers below and form still doesn't submit you data you can share your php part with us

Comment: `submit.php` is different file? or same file

Comment: It is different file

Comment: different file and same root? if yes, than use `print_r($_POST)` in submit.php

Comment: I added it but its not working

Answer (score 2):

If you are really using the button at bottom `I also gave a button submit` and you also need to add `</form>` closing form tag.

also note that, this input will return nothing:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" required>
```

Because you are not using name attribute here.

You also need to add name attribute for `Batch Number` field.

```
<input type="number" placeholder='Batch Number' class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{9}" required>
```

**Update:**

As per your comments, you are using button and closing form tag, it means, this is pure PHP issue not related to form action.

What you need here:

- You must need to check either `submit.php` available on same root or not, or if you have only one file than leave it blank `<form action="">`
- In submit.php file you also need to check the post values like `print_r($_POST)` check what are you getting and add missing name attributes.
- Most important part is that, don't know are you using `isset()` or not, how can you check either submit button isset or not with this input:
  `<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="background:#cddc39;color:#F44336;padding:5px 30px 25px 20px;">`

Comment: Even if I add a name attribute and mentioned print_r($_POST) in submit.php but I am not getting the output

Comment: @BhargaviK: share the submit.php file

Comment: <?php print_r($_POST); ?>   I gave only this because I just need to redirect the page when i click on submit.

Comment: Is that whole whole source code from submit.php `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`?

Comment: Yes because I just want to check whether my button is working or not

Comment: for the debugging, `action="submit.php"` remove submit.php from here, leave it empty, and add `print_r($_POST)` at top in same file.

Comment: @BhargaviK: did u checked the above mentioned?

Comment: yes but it nots working.It is showing the output for print_r($_POST) as array()

Answer (score 0):

below is the code that is working fine.
form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Popup Timepicker Demo Using AngularJS, Bootstrap</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description"
    content="Popup Timepicker Demo Using AngularJS, Bootstrap.">

</head>
<body>
 <form action="submit.php" method="POST">
        <tbody>
            <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" class="hidden">
            <td data-name="loannum">
              <input type="number" name="name1" class="form-control" required>
            </td>
            <td data-name="name">
              <input id="startdate" name="startdate" min="2016-01-01" max="2020-01-01" type="date" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td data-name="name">
                <input type="text" name='gname' placeholder='Group Name' class="form-control"  pattern="([A-z\s]){2,}" required/>
            </td>
            <td data-name="desc">
                <input type="number" name="name2" placeholder='Batch Number' class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{9}" required>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div> </div> <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary" style="background:#84ca71;color:#F44336;padding-bottom:24px;‌​">Add Group</a> <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="background:#cddc39;color:#F44336;padding:5px 30px 25px 20px;">submit</button> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the submit.php code which is in the same folder of form.html.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: can you please tell me what kind of problem you face i can help you

Comment: <?php
print_r($_POST);
?>

Comment: copy all the above code of form.html and then submit form

Comment: are you getting blank array?

Comment: above code working fine in my pc perhaps it is php issues for posting data.please try method="get" and in php side <?php print_r($_GET); ?> and check it is working or not

Comment: check below link perhaps it help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127142/html-form-just-wont-send-some-post-variables-to-a-php-script