# I can't upload files larger than 8 mb

Tags: php

I created a php script with a limit of 500mb but it does not work. I have read that it could be due to php.ini size limit but I can't find php.ini in the server where the site is located.
Anyway, if somebody has got an idea about what more I can do apart from modificating the php.ini file, please tell me.

Thank you

EDIT: I have been in contant with my hosting provider and they can't set the "upload_max_filesize" variable up to 64Mb. I looked for information about VPS and I have found out that it needs advanced knowledge in network systems which I do not have... Would it be any other alternative to this?
Moreover, the hosting provider offered me a VPS managed by them but the cost is too high (about 150€/month).

Comment: I can't find the file "php.ini". Could you tell me where is it?

Comment: check if there is a file named '.user.ini' in your public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're using shared hosting. Contact your hosting provider, they're probably limiting your `upload_max_filesize` because you're on shared hosting. If this is the case I'm not sure or anything that will fix it other than getting a VPN

Comment: I have been in contant with my hosting provider and they can't set the "upload_max_filesize" variable up to 64Mb. I looked for information about VPS and I have found out that it needs advanced knowledge in network systems which I do not have... Would it be any other alternative to this?
Moreover, the hosting provider offered me a VPS managed by them but the cost is too high (about 150€/month).

Comment: Take a look at Godaddy. https://www.godaddy.com/pro/managed-vps

Answer (score 4):

edit the file `php.ini` to your server and set these variables:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500MB
post_max_size = 500MB
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/it/ini.core.php

Answer (score 1):

Find your servers php.ini file, usually located in /etc directory (if you have full server access) and change the following:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to your `/etc/php.ini` you can use `.htacess`

See this answer: [How to set upload_max_filesize in .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess)