# How to Fix php value error in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

When i put php value in `.htaccess` below is code
then server giving Internal server error please fix that issue i have sent screen shot

[image: Internal server error]

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Comment: We need error message from log files. Screen you have send do not explain error. All code you show is ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set upload\_max\_filesize in .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess)

Comment: that is not in .httaccess, but in php.ini

Comment: You probably are not allowed to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct way. In this case your hosting provider or your installation is not allowing you to adjust those settings through .htaccess. You should contact your hosting provider.

Ask them to enable `AllowOverride Options` for you in apache.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html