# how to setup .user.ini in local xampp server

Tags: php, configuration

I wanna change the `upload_max_filesize` value without changing the `php.ini` file.
In the process of searching, I got to know that by using `.user.ini` file also, we can change the `upload_max_filesize`. I have made the `.user.ini` as follows
`upload_max_filesize = 50M` and placed the file in xampp folder But not working as expected, where did I do wrong? where should I place the file to effect? Please suggest me right way to achieve.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) states that `.user.ini` are like `.htaccess` files and work on a per-directory basis. The same doc's also state that you can achieve the same results by using `.htaccess` files in case you are running php as Apache module. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess), [This article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-php-maximum-upload-file-size-in-an-htaccess-file) and [This part of doc's](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) also shed some light on what can be set inside `.user.ini` files.

Now considering that you are using xammp and judging by the doc's:

Looks like instead of using `.user.ini` you are better off using `.htaccess`. Also as far as I got it `php.ini` must have `user_ini.filename` set and uncommented and also `.user.ini` must be located in the same folder as `.htaccess` for a site/script/setup. For xammp `.htaccess` place greatly depends on setups. For exaple site sourse code can be placed in a separate folder inside htdocs folder (Virtual hosts). But it's only one way of setups.

This is not really an answer, but all this research did not fit in the comments.